# How to revoke older reference token when client request for new reference token in IdentityServer3?

Tags: identityserver3

I have a scenario where the client is invoking http://localhost/connect/token endpoint to get reference token (Note: this is grant_type = client_credentials), if client_id, client_secret & scope matches then IdentityServer will return valid reference token. Let's say this reference token is valid for 1 day.

Now after sometimes(say 30 minutes or so) client requesting again for new reference token and IdentityServer return new reference token.

Is there any way to revoke old reference token and client can only use new reference token?

Answer (score 0):

Use method `ITokenHandleStore.RemoveAsync(string)` to revoke particular token.

You can override method `ITokenHandleStore.StoreAsync(string, Token)` to remove old token prior to storing new token. However you'll need to create your own implementation of [`ITokenHandleStore`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Core/Services/ITokenHandleStore.cs).

On the other hand, your users can call [token revocation endpoint](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/revocation.html) to revoke tokens on their own.

Comment: Let me try this.

Comment: In StoreAsync the key is N39kmX__fyuj9SmieMwBBvkzG_uyyh1auciN4AI7vuE, when it gets to the client its c1bfe900d8350d9ba4a199c213873537. I'd like to store what the client receives from identityserver3, Can you please help me to understand how to store access token at StoreAsync () event?